# Can I add additional datadisk through ARM Template while creating a VM in Azure from an existing image which already has a datadisk?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template, azure-vm

I am creating a VM in Azure through ARM Template using an existing image. The image already has a datadisk. I am trying to add additional data-disks through ARM Template while creating the VM. Can I do so ? I am getting below listed error:-

```
Can not add property dataDisks to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject. Property with the same name already exists on object
```

Comment: Please share your template and do you know which lun does the data disk use in the VM imnage?

Comment: @Charles is it allowed to add additional data disks while creating VM if the image which is used already has data disks ? Template sharing would be tough because of compliance issues.

Comment: You can try to find the `lun` which the existing data disk in, and then set the additional data disk at another `lun` in the template.

Comment: @CharlesXu I am using like this in VM template, I guess it is same in image also-

    "lun": 0

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your image already has data disks, then when you create the VM through the ARM template, you need also configure the `datadisk` block for the existing data disk. Just set the `createOption` with the value `fromImage`. Then set the additional data disk as usual. For example, your image has one data disk, and you also need to attach another data disk, then the `dataDisk` block would like this:

```
"dataDisks": [
    {
        "lun": 0,
        "createOption": "fromImage",
        "caching": "ReadOnly",
        "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false,
        "id": null,
        "name": null,
        "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS",
        "diskSizeGB": null,
        "diskEncryptionSet": null
    },
    {
        "lun": 1,
        "createOption": "attach",
        "caching": "None",
        "writeAcceleratorEnabled": false,
        "id": null,
        "name": "azurevm_DataDisk_1",
        "storageAccountType": null,
        "diskSizeGB": null,
        "diskEncryptionSet": null
    }
]
```

It's just an example, you can change the values as you need, the most important thing for you is the `createOption`. And the first is for the existing data disk, the same type, and other things also should be the same as it is in the image.